# flex setting button width to text width

Tags: apache-flex

I am creating a nav in flex that pulls in buttons dynamically from xml.  THe problem i am having is setting the button width to the text width. currently the buttons are all the same width and if the text is larger then it just cuts off. I've tried a few ways of doing this:

1. Setting button width to 100%
2. On creation of the button try to set the width of the button to the text programmatically. Something like evt.target.width = evt.target.textWidth;

Anyone know the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

> By default, Flex stretches the Button
>   control width to fit the size of its
>   label, any icon, plus 6 pixels of
>   padding around the icon. You can
>   override this default width by
>   explicitly setting the width  property
>   of the Button control to a specific
>   value or to a percentage of its parent
>   container. If you specify a percentage
>   value, the button resizes between its
>   minimum and maximum widths as the size
>   of its parent container changes.

From *Sizing a Button control* section in [this live docs](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=controls_04.html) page. As far as I can understand from this is, If you remove the width= form your code, it should give what you want.